# How can I change the plymouth booting animation on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: boot, gnome, themes, 19.04, plymouth

I have downloaded a Plymouth theme from Gnome-loo.org. And since it was a deb package, I installed it through Ubuntu Software. Then, I typed "sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth" and selected the newly added theme. But it didn't work out at all, and Plymouth theme didn't change. If you know how to do it properly, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the link of Plymouth theme...you downl0aded..

Comment: did you run `sudo update-initramfs -u `command??

Comment: PRATAP, here is the link to the theme: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1009776/

Comment: And yes, I have run sudo update-initramfs -u

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be its 2010 Created plymouth theme and the script is written to keep the plymouth theme directory under `/lib/plymouth/themes/` as opposed to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/` for the recent versions..

by extracting the directory `space-sunrise` from the downloaded `.deb` file.. and editing the content like below in the space-sunrise.plymouth file it is possible to freshly install as a new theme under `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/` directory.

[image]

```
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/space-sunrise
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/space-sunrise/space-sunrise.script
```

1. after editing the file at downloaded location.. copy the directory `space-sunrise` from downloaded location to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/`
2. the `.deb` file is really messing up the things with outdated path.. I could not remove the path with `sudo update-alternatives` so I removed the complete package of plymouth..
3. `sudo apt purge plymouth`
4. reboot..
5. `sudo apt install plymouth`
6. `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/space-sunrise/space-sunrise.plymouth 200`
7. `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
8. select the number of your choice
9. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
10. Reboot..

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. By the way, I have one more question. How should I extract the deb file? I just used "dpkg -x package.deb/usr/share/plymouth/themes/, but it didn't work out.

Comment: just right click the .deb file.. the option `extract` here or similar will show.. you can see the path in attached pics in answer.. first time you extract.. there will be sub folders.. again extract..required folder is in `data` directory..